# How to trigger background-processes, how to receive intermediate results?

Tags: node.js, ajax, background-process, puppeteer, sharp

I have a NodeJS / background-process issue, that I don't know how to solve it 'elegant', straight, the right way.

The user submits some (like ~10 or more) URLs via a textarea and then they should be processed asynchronous. [a screenshot with puppeteer has to be taken, some information gathered, the screenshot should be processed with sharp and the result should be persisted in a MongoDB. The screenshot via GridFS and the URL in an own collection with a reference to the screenshot].

While this async process is calculated in the background, the page should be updated whenever a URL got processed.

There are so many ways to do that, but which one is the most correct/straightforward/resource saving way?

Browserify and I do it in the browser? No, too much stuff on the client side.. AJAX/Axios posts and wait for the URLs to be processed and reflect the results on the side? Trigger the process before the response gets send back to the client or let the client start the processing?

Answer (score 0):

So, I made a workflow engine of some sort that supports long-running jobs. And I followed this tutorial https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/

Which is nothing, when a request is created you just return a status code and when the jobs are completed you just log them somewhere and use that.

For, this I used `EventEmitter` which is used inside a promise. It's only my solution maybe not elegant, maybe outright wrong. Made a little POC for you.

```
const events = require('events')
const emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

const actualWork = function() {
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        setTimeout(res, 1000);
    })
}
emitter.on('workCompleted', function(){
    // log somewhere
});

app.get('/someroute', (req,res)=>{
    res.json({msg:'reqest initiated', id: 'some_id'})
    actualWork()
    .then(()=>{
        emitter.emit('workCompleted', {id: 'some_id'});
    });
})
app.get('/someroute/id/status', (req,res)=>{
    //get the log
})
```